Npm install with private git repo dependency stopped working
I have a package.json file with "rtrk": "https://github.com/me/rtrk.git", entry among the dependencies.
Until today I could normally run npm install or npm update rtrk commands and they would work.
Today, the npm install (update would behave the same) took around 8 minutes until it resulted in an error.
I tried rolling back the versions of both the app and the package to yesterday's versions.
I tried changing the package.json entry to "rtrk": "git+https://github.com/me/rtrk.git",.
I tried deleting the node_modules directory and package-lock.json file.
I tried npm config set cafile C:\laragon\etc\ssl\cacert.pem.
None of these helped.
I tried npm config set strict-ssl false which allowed me to run the commands, but it's only a temporary solution.
Tested devices: Two windows pcs are getting the same error. Macbook can run the commands properly.
Devices dont have active proxies.
EDIT: If I remove my package from the dependencies, npm works. So is it really a certificate issue? Could the certificate of the package be bad somehow? I mean, does the package even have a certificate?
Interesting parts of the error log:
63 timing idealTree:node_modules/rtrk Completed in 140402ms
64 timing idealTree:node_modules/svelte-radix Completed in 0ms
65 silly placeDep node_modules/rtrk @melt-ui/svelte@0.74.4 OK for: bits-ui@0.18.6 want: 0.74.4
66 silly placeDep node_modules/rtrk nanoid@5.0.7 OK for: bits-ui@0.18.6 want: ^5.0.5
67 silly fetch manifest nanoid@^5.0.4
68 timing idealTree:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/bits-ui Completed in 8ms
69 timing idealTree:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/@melt-ui/svelte Completed in 0ms
70 timing idealTree:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/nanoid Completed in 0ms
71 timing idealTree:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/tailwind-variants Completed in 0ms
72 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 423551ms
73 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 4ms
74 timing idealTree Completed in 423766ms
75 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 423768ms

190 verbose audit error FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
190 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ratrakone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
190 verbose audit error     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
190 verbose audit error     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
190 verbose audit error     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
190 verbose audit error     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
190 verbose audit error   code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
190 verbose audit error   errno: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',
190 verbose audit error   type: 'system'

195 timing reifyNode:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/@melt-ui/svelte Completed in 656ms
196 timing reifyNode:node_modules/svelte-radix Completed in 766ms
197 timing reifyNode:node_modules/rtrk/node_modules/bits-ui Completed in 852ms
198 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 147ms
199 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
200 timing command:install Completed in 494519ms

202 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://codeload.github.com/me/rtrk/tar.gz/ef070543e1b4febb1934379cd12df37e8af9545e failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
202 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ratrakone\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:130:14)
202 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
202 verbose stack     at _destroy (node:_http_client:875:13)
202 verbose stack     at onSocketNT (node:_http_client:895:5)
202 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
203 verbose cwd C:\custom\dev\my_app
204 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
205 verbose node v20.11.1
206 verbose npm  v10.5.1
207 error code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
208 error errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
209 error request to https://codeload.github.com/me/rtrk/tar.gz/ef070543e1b4febb1934379cd12df37e8af9545e failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
210 verbose exit 1
211 timing npm Completed in 494896ms
212 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1713556823504
213 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:unpack 1713557247314
214 verbose unfinished npm timer reifyNode:node_modules/rtrk 1713557247314
215 verbose code 1

I also looked up the VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE questions on stackoverflow, but those suggested a certificate problems, which shouldn't be my case as everything worked for months, including yesterday.

UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE do suggests that it is a certificate issue. Is it possible that you have any MITM proxy enabled (for testing/debugging purposes)? https://registry.npmjs.org cert is issued last year so I assume it wouldn't be the case where you have outdated CA list in your device. What happened if you open https://registry.npmjs.org  in your browser? Does your browser complain about unable to verify certificate?

it responds with { }. why would it matter? i didn't publish the package to the npm. and as i mentioned - it has no probelm running on the mac. all windows pcs do have the problem.

also i don't have any proxy enabled.

Antivirus by ESET causes this issue.
It's their new "feature" as mentioned on this forum.
It's solveable either by disabling HTTPS traffic scanning in the AV settings.
Or adding the certificate manually. Which helped a lot of user, but didn't solve my case so I still had to disable scanning the traffic.
Four days lost, gg ESET.
